# Verificação do total de digitos no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Bem, preciso selecionar valores formados por um total de 5 dígitos que iniciem com “1” e terminem com “0”. Na tabela, esse atributo é do tipo decimal. Como posso realizar esse SELECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você faria da seguinte forma:

```
 SELECT * from minha_tabela where meu_campo between 10000 and 19999 and mod(meu_campo ,10) = 0
```

Comment: Também poderia ser: SELECT * from minha_tabela where (meu_campo DIV 1000 = 1) and mod(meu_campo ,10) = 0;